# how to minimize the product of sum from canonical pos?

Tags: digital-logic

I have a canonical pos form which is derived from SOP by using De Morgan's law.

*POS*:

(A+B+C) (A+B+C') (A+B'+C')

So I need to reduce this to min pos.

May I know, how to get like this form (A+B) (A+C')?

I know some basic boolean algebra rules, but i just confused, how to apply.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Poor DeMorgan...Anyway, using the Karnaugh map with circling the zeros will produce the minimal PoS.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, now i am learning minimize by using algebra.. further i move to k-map method.. and you told poor De-margon..so may i know ,what is the best one @Eugene

Comment: I said he is poor because you are distorting the guy's name. He doesn't deserve it. Good luck with the algebra.

Comment: Sorry,,, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so:

```
  (A+B+C) (A+B+C') (A+B'+C')

= ((A+B+C) (A+B+C')) ((A+B+C') (A+B'+C'))

= (A+B+(CC')) (A+C'+(BB'))

= (A+B+0) (A+C'+0)

= (A+B) (A+C')
```

Comment: I can't understand the second line, help me again, thanks..

Comment: It's a reversal of the axiom `AA = A`. We simply duplicate the middle term so that it can be used in both simplification operations.

Comment: Thanks.,,may i know, what is this name of this procedure?

Comment: 2 uses Idempotent Law

Comment: Yes, offcourse i know, AA=A is idempotent law,, in my example, where is use.. ans what is A? Thanks ...

Comment: The term that got duplicated. You can add as many arbitrary terms as you like so long as it doesn't change the final result.

Comment: Better if I use X.  In this case X = (A+B+C'), so XX = X (and X + X = X).  You can duplicate terms as needed.  So boolean laws look at reductions, but you can go either way.  Typically boolean laws use XYZ or ABC.  He probably should of used X, since A is used in question.